# How does PlayDominion´s rating system work?

Tags: dominion

Does anyone know how the rating system on [PlayDominion.com](https://www.playdominion.com/Dominion/gameClient.html) works?  I am familiar with the chess rating system, which is quite, but this is not the one used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the Microsoft TrueSkill rating system, with some changes to how the value is displayed (mainly to stop the displayed value becoming negative, or going down after you win a game). It was [reverse engineered](http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=10869.0) back in April 2014.

Comment: http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=67956 is a link I found after your post.  It does sound like a reasonably well thought out system (perhaps my initial misgivings about it is that it just is not the chess rating system that I am familiar with).